# Adding data from JSON url using messes up with a query (HTML table)

Tags: javascript, html, json, filter

A short description :

**01)** I dynamically load data from a JSON url into an HTML table. The script is in the external `.js` file called in the header of the `HTML` file.

**02)** I filter the results using a filter at the top of the page for the third column (MAIN VALUE). The script worked fine when I had static data. It stopped working ever since I started pullimg the table data dynamically from a JSON url.

And the JS script is here :

```
        //It loads the data from the JSON file 
    $.getJSON(
         'http://apolosiskos.co.uk/TEB/MOCK_DATA.json',
         function(data){
             var tr;
    //It loads data from the JSON file to the table
             $.each (data, function (key, val) {
                tr = $('<tr/>');
                tr.append('<td class="name" rel="' + val.first_name + '">' + val.first_name + '</td>');
                tr.append('<td >' + 'TEST' + '</td>');
                tr.append('<td class="metric2" >' + val.id + '</td>');
                tr.append('<td class="metric3"><span class="multTotal">' +'0.00'+ '</span></td>');
            tr.append('<td class="metric3-100"><span class="metric3-100">' +'0.00'+ '</span></td>');
            tr.append('<td class="metric1-100"><span class="metric1-100">' +'0.00'+ '</span></td>');
                $('table').append(tr);
             });
            $("input").keyup(minmax);
            //I even tried the below but did not work
            $('body').on('input', '#counter-low, #counter-high', minmax);
           });

    //The filter function for the MIN MAX values in the MAIN VALUE column
    function minmax() {
        var table = $('table').DataTable();
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
            return parseFloat(data[2]) >= parseFloat($('#counter-low').val() || data[2]) 
                && parseFloat(data[2]) <= parseFloat($('#counter-high').val() || data[2])
        });
        $('#counter-low, #counter-high').on('keyup', table.draw);
    }
```

**UPD**: I paste the code here that works after an answer below :

```
$(function(){

//It loads the data from the JSON file 
$.getJSON(
     'http://apolosiskos.co.uk/TEB/MOCK_DATA.json',
     function(data){
         var tr;
//It loads data from the JSON file to the table
         $.each (data, function (key, val) {
            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append('<td class="name" rel="' + val.first_name + '">' + val.first_name + '</td>');
            tr.append('<td ><input class="metric1"/>' + '</td>');
            tr.append('<td class="metric2" >' + val.id + '</td>');
            tr.append('<td class="metric3"><span class="multTotal">' +'0.00'+ '</span></td>');
        tr.append('<td class="metric3-100"><span class="metric3-100">' +'0.00'+ '</span></td>');
        tr.append('<td class="metric1-100"><span class="metric1-100">' +'0.00'+ '</span></td>');
            $('table').append(tr);
         });
//It loads dimension1 from the JSON file to the filter
         $.each (data, function (key, val) {
            li = $('<li/>');
            li.append('<input rel="name" type="checkbox" value="' + val.first_name + '"><label for="cb1">' + val.first_name + '</label></li>');
            $('ul').append(li);
         });
       $('.counter').keyup(minmax);
       $('body').on('input click', 'input:checkbox', filters);
       });

});

//Multiplication of the cells function
function multInputs() {
    var mult = 0;
    $("tr").each(function () {
        var $val1 = $('.metric1', this).val();
        var $val2 = $('.metric2', this).text();
        var $total = ($val1 * 1) * $val2 - $val1;
        $('.multTotal', this).text($total.toPrecision(3));

        var $val3 = $('.multTotal', this).text();
        var $total2 = $val3 / 100
        $('.metric3-100',this).text($total2.toPrecision(3));

        var $total3 = $val1 / 100
        $('.metric1-100',this).text($total3.toPrecision(2));

        mult += $total;
    });
}

//Filter function for the Dimension1 values
function filters() {
    var showAll = true;
    $('tr').not('.first').hide();
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        if ($(this)[0].checked) {
            showAll = false;
            var dimension1= $(this).attr('rel');
            var value = $(this).val();            
            $('td.' + dimension1+ '[rel="' + value + '"]').parent('tr').show();
        }
    });
    if(showAll){
        $('tr').show();
    }
}

//The filter function for the MIN MAX values in the MAIN VALUE column
    function minmax() {
        var table = $('table').DataTable();
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
            return parseFloat(data[2]) >= parseFloat($('#counter-low').val() || data[2]) 
                && parseFloat(data[2]) <= parseFloat($('#counter-high').val() || data[2])
        });
        $('#counter-low, #counter-high').on('keyup', table.draw);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, answering here, I have downloaded your html, json and js.
And then I had 3 changes.

1. I put everything inside the `$(function(){});`to JS execute everything just after the entire DOM is loaded.
2. Add a class in both of min and max input like:

   `<input id="counter-min" class="counter"/>`

   `<input id="counter-max" class="counter"/>`

and in js set up to `$('.counter').keyup( minmax )`; having this minmax as a function you already created;

3. I put the table html like this one:

   `<table>
       <thead>
           <tr id="ProductID" class="first">
               <th>NAME</th>
               <th>INPUT</th>
               <th>MAIN VALUE</th>
               <th>DIFF</th>
               <th>DIFF /100</th>
               <th>MV /100</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody> </tbody>
   </table>`

So, that's have worked for me, I don't know if is

**EDIT, for the second time**
I do it here, I just have commented your getJson to add the data directly on your table and then, I did what I said before:

1 - use the `$(function() { .. });`

2 - add classes on the counter-high and counter-low, just to attach the event to them and then attached the event with `$('.className').keyup( minmax );`
and

3 - add the thead and tbody elements in the table

```js
//It loads the data from the JSON file 
$(function() {
  
    var data = [{"id":2.2,"first_name":"Debra","last_name":"Rodriguez","email":"drodriguez0@admin.ch","gender":"Female","ip_address":"90.22.159.108"},
{"id":2,"first_name":"Julie","last_name":"Lynch","email":"jlynch1@tumblr.com","gender":"Female","ip_address":"54.182.62.180"},
{"id":3,"first_name":"Norma","last_name":"Washington","email":"nwashington2@theatlantic.com","gender":"Female","ip_address":"70.163.106.64"},
{"id":4,"first_name":"Bobby","last_name":"Castillo","email":"bcastillo3@nbcnews.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"91.202.59.171"},
{"id":5,"first_name":"Henry","last_name":"Chavez","email":"hchavez4@chronoengine.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"32.237.37.185"},
{"id":6,"first_name":"Debra","last_name":"Howard","email":"showard5@stumbleupon.com","gender":"Female","ip_address":"17.217.42.49"},
{"id":7,"first_name":"Jason","last_name":"Powell","email":"jpowell6@telegraph.co.uk","gender":"Male","ip_address":"14.81.195.117"},
{"id":8,"first_name":"Sean","last_name":"Burns","email":"sburns7@hp.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"213.164.85.212"},
{"id":9,"first_name":"Jacqueline","last_name":"Gordon","email":"jgordon8@bloglines.com","gender":"Female","ip_address":"18.251.62.55"},
{"id":10,"first_name":"Russell","last_name":"Richards","email":"rrichards9@com.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"27.226.59.80"},
{"id":11,"first_name":"Albert","last_name":"Perkins","email":"aperkinsa@hc360.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"243.122.251.248"},
{"id":12,"first_name":"Michael","last_name":"Willis","email":"mwillisb@deviantart.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"252.197.211.230"},
{"id":13,"first_name":"Joan","last_name":"Hamilton","email":"jhamiltonc@weebly.com","gender":"Female","ip_address":"204.70.110.117"},
{"id":14,"first_name":"Eric","last_name":"Garcia","email":"egarciad@yahoo.co.jp","gender":"Male","ip_address":"178.221.216.3"},
{"id":15,"first_name":"Frank","last_name":"Olson","email":"folsone@amazon.co.uk","gender":"Male","ip_address":"245.25.170.33"},
{"id":16,"first_name":"Kelly","last_name":"Fuller","email":"kfullerf@tripod.com","gender":"Female","ip_address":"199.209.173.51"},
{"id":17,"first_name":"Frank","last_name":"Cook","email":"fcookg@google.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"58.30.243.1"},
{"id":18,"first_name":"Alan","last_name":"Rice","email":"ariceh@sciencedirect.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"44.231.199.117"},
{"id":19,"first_name":"Mark","last_name":"Greene","email":"mgreenei@paypal.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"45.34.44.2"},
{"id":20,"first_name":"Charles","last_name":"King","email":"ckingj@clickbank.net","gender":"Male","ip_address":"237.30.205.186"}];
  
    //$.getJSON(
        //'http://apolosiskos.co.uk/TEB/MOCK_DATA.json',
        //function(data) {
            var tr;
            //It loads data from the JSON file to the table
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                tr = $('<tr/>');
                tr.append('<td class="name" rel="' + val.first_name + '">' + val.first_name + '</td>');
                tr.append('<td >' + 'TEST' + '</td>');
                tr.append('<td class="metric2" >' + val.id + '</td>');
                tr.append('<td class="metric3"><span class="multTotal">' + '0.00' + '</span></td>');
                tr.append('<td class="metric3-100"><span class="metric3-100">' + '0.00' + '</span></td>');
                tr.append('<td class="metric1-100"><span class="metric1-100">' + '0.00' + '</span></td>');
                $('table').append(tr);
            });
   
            $('body').on('click', 'input[type=checkbox]', minmax);
            $('.counter').keyup(minmax);
            $('input').keyup(multInputs);
            $('body').on('click', '#btnFilter', filtermin);
        });
//});


//The filter function for the first column (NAME)
//This have to work together of the minmax function
function filters() {
 
 //if anyone is checked, return true to show all
 var checkboxChecked = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
 if (checkboxChecked.length <= 0) {
  $('tr').show();
  return true;
 }
 
 $('tr').not('.first').hide();
 //else, find the name checked and verify with the name passed as parameter
 
    checkboxChecked.each(function() {
  var dimension1 = $(this).attr('rel');
  var value = $(this).val();
  
  $('td.' + dimension1 + '[rel="' + value + '"]').parent('tr').show();
    });
}

//Multiplication of the cells function
function multInputs() {
    var mult = 0;
    $("tr").each(function() {
        var $val1 = $('.metric1', this).val();
        var $val2 = $('.metric2', this).text();
        var $total = ($val1 * 1) * $val2 - $val1;
        $('.multTotal', this).text($total.toPrecision(3));

        var $val3 = $('.multTotal', this).text();
        var $total2 = $val3 / 100
        $('.metric3-100', this).text($total2.toPrecision(3));

        var $total3 = $val1 / 100
        $('.metric1-100', this).text($total3.toPrecision(2));

        mult += $total;
    });
}

//The filter function for the MIN MAX values in the MAIN VALUE column
function minmax() {
 
 filters();
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
        return parseFloat(data[2]) >= parseFloat($('#counter-low').val() || data[2]) &&
            parseFloat(data[2]) <= parseFloat($('#counter-high').val() || data[2]);
    });
 
 var table = $('table').DataTable();
    $('#counter-low, #counter-high').on('keyup', table.draw);
}

function filtermin() {
    var value = $('#filter').val();

    $('tr').show();

    $('tr td.odds').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() < value) {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        }
    });

}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*" />
    <title>json extract in datorama tables</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="teste.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
    <style href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>discrepancy checker after extracting data in JSON</h1>
    <hr/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 filter-columns">
            <div class="ac-custom ac-checkbox ac-cross" autocomplete="off">
                <h2>Dimension1</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><input rel="name" type="checkbox" value="Debra" id="cb1"><label for="cb1">Debra</label></li>
                    <li><input rel="name" type="checkbox" value="Julie" id="cb2"><label for="cb2">Julie</label></li>
                    <li><input rel="name" type="checkbox" value="Norma" id="cb3"><label for="cb3">Norma</label></li>
                    <li><input rel="name" type="checkbox" value="Bobby" id="cb4"><label for="cb4">Bobby</label></li>
                    <li><input rel="name" type="checkbox" value="Henry" id="cb5"><label for="cb5">Henry</label></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 filter-columns-alt">
            <div class="ac-custom ac-checkbox ac-cross" autocomplete="off">
                <h2>MIN MAX</h2>
                Min:<input id="counter-low"  class="counter" type="text" /> &nbsp; 
    Max:<input id="counter-high" class="counter" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 filter-columns-alt">
            <input type='text' id='filter' /> <button id='btnFilter'>Go</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="body">


        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr id="ProductID" class="first">
                    <th>NAME</th>
                    <th>INPUT</th>
                    <th>MAIN VALUE</th>
                    <th>DIFF</th>
                    <th>DIFF /100</th>
                    <th>MV /100</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I did not get the step 1 to be honest. I have never unified functions in JS.

Comment: the step 1: 
put all your js code into $(function(){ ... put your code here... }); just your functions filters and minmax doesn't need..

this $(function(){ ... }); is the same of $(document).ready(function() { ... }); which means, that all your js, will execute just after the document stay ready, you know?

so, all your DOM elements will be created and then your js will execute, that way, you prevent some errors.

Comment: It seems to be working but there is an implication between the filters and minmax function. If you type min 15, then choose Debra and then change the min to 5, the filters do not work.

Comment: I updated the link if that helps. Replace the test2.html with jsontest.html

Comment: @ApoloRadomer, you have to do the minmax and filters work together, I edited the code snippet again and now you can filter by name and min max value... I put the filters function inside de minmax, and I put the minmax to be executed by checboxes too... you, now you have to change the name of the funcions or merge then, etc..

Comment: I will try to merget them. The next challenge is to also load the filter values from the JSON. I did it before but I think it takes a while to load.

Comment: you cold load all normally, and after load the data, you call the functions to filter

Comment: It is not loading some values like Julie. Trying to find out why.

Comment: I changed the first filter and that was automatically resolved. Now, the MINMAX is not working. I ll check this out  to see why. The link ends in TEB/test.html

Comment: I think is something because of table pagination, what you could do is always manage the json data and fill the table again (I thinks this discussion is being very large, I didn't read all the rules about stackoverflow yet, but, if my answer helped you, please, check it like accepted and close the question and maybe we could start a chat about your problems ~ always when I click to add a new comment, a label appear saying "please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?")

Comment: I will. Let's move in the chat.

Comment: Should I create a new room?

Comment: I think I should raise a new ticket for the MINMAX filter. I ll let you know here.

Comment: A new question came out.